# Should I ask a moderator to reject an edit before it's robo-reviewed and approved?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits

During today's edits I came across an edit so terrible it changed so much of the answer and so much **meaning** of the answer that I thought it was an audit!

Knowing that often, terrible edits slip through and perfectly fine edits are rejected due to fat-fingered quick reviewing, should I ask a moderator (or enough people who would see this question with review privleges) to reject this edit?

Comment: Posting a new question to gather Reject votes is not an appropriate use of Meta.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. Is there something better I could have done?

Comment: Done before I could even get there :) You might consider bringing up future issues like this in an active chat room, even the SO Tavern if you can't find a good subject specific one.

Comment: in this particular case it would be simpler to use reject-and-edit to cut it down unilaterally (shame on me for missing that). Answer spelling could be corrected: "returns you what exactlu you want just pass your string array thats it" -> "returns exactly what you want. Just pass your string array and that's it"

Comment: @James Suggested edits tend to get reviewed very quickly. If an edit is so bad you want to make sure it doesn't go through, just keep the review item in a tab and check occasionally to see what its status is. If it gets approved, roll it back. You don't really need to go searching for others to step in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better solution to this is to do one of the following:

- "Reject and Edit" the pending edit and make an edit of your own, overwriting the original.
- > "Suggested edits tend to get reviewed very quickly. If an edit is so bad you want to make sure it doesn't go through, just keep the review item in a tab and check occasionally to see what its status is. If it gets approved, roll it back"

Comment: Good resolution, posting this answer. May I suggest editing the question as well, to make it more along the lines of a "should I ask for help on Meta with rejecting terrible suggestions?" FAQ-ish post?

Comment: Probably a good idea as I'm garnering a few down votes at the minute :P

Comment: Note that reviewers generally have at least 3 minutes of exclusivity now, so no need to be in *too much* of a hurry @LittleBobbyTables.

Comment: It was an absolute relief when that was finally implemented, @Shog9. It has made a major impact for me.